# сортировка массива лестницей java

Tags: java, динамические-массивы

Доброго времени суток. Я начинающий программист на java. Тут мне задали вопрос а знаешь ли ты как делается сортировка лестницей? Ну пузырьком я знаю(и от большего к меньшему и от меньшего к большему). Про лестницу только услышал.

```
for(int = j; j < array.lenght; j++){
for(int i = j + 1; i = array.lenght; i=+){
    if(array[j] < array[i]){
        int temp = (int) array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
}}
```

Comment: Не слышал про такой метод сортировки, и гугл молчит. Можете описать общий алгоритм?

Comment: есть массив [2, -3, 23, 4, 21, -10] и как мне объяснили должен работать по принципу (в 1 проход вычисляет минимальное значение 2 проход следующее по величине и так далее)    [-10, -3, 23, 4, 21, 2][-10, -3, 23, 4, 21, 2][-10, -3, 2, 4, 21, 23] и последняя проверка выводит [-10, -3, 2, 4, 21, 23]

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

            static void printArr(int[] array) {
                Arrays.stream(array).forEach((el) -> System.out.print(el + " "));
                System.out.println();
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                int[] arr = {2, -3, 23, 4, 21, -10};

                int minValueIndex = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

                    for (int i = j; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        if (arr[i] < min) {
                            min = arr[i];
                            minValueIndex = i;
                        }
                    }

                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[minValueIndex];
                    arr[minValueIndex] = temp;

                    printArr(arr);

                }
            }
        }

    //        -10 -3 23 4 21 2
    //        -10 -3 23 4 21 2
    //        -10 -3 2 4 21 23
    //        -10 -3 2 4 21 23
    //        -10 -3 2 4 21 23
    //        -10 -3 2 4 21 23
```